# Debugger settings: codeblock osx

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, gcc4.9

1. I have CodeBlocks 13.12 (CodeBlocks-13.12-mac) installed on OSX 10.9.2 (Mavericks).
2. I am using gcc 4.9 and have gdb (7.7.1) installed.
3. I am able to successfully build and run simple programs.
4. But when I try to "debug" (e.g., "run to cursor"), I get the following output:

   > [debug]Command-line: /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.7.1/bin/gdb -nx -fullname
   >   -quiet  -args /Users/skips/SkipsC++Code/DebugTutorial/bin/Debug/DebugTutorial
   >   [debug]Working dir : /Users/skips/SkipsC++Code/DebugTutorial Starting
   >   debugger: /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.7.1/bin/gdb -nx -fullname  -quiet 
   >   -args /Users/skips/SkipsC++Code/DebugTutorial/bin/Debug/DebugTutorial
   >
   > done
   >
   > [debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:
   >   Registered new type: wxString
   >   Registered new type: STL String
   >   Registered new type: STL Vector
   >   Setting breakpoints
   >
   > Can't launch console (osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script ""' -e 'end tell' sleep 80007329)
   >   .
   >   .
   >   .
   >   Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1
   >   .
   >   .
   >   .
   >   [debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
   >   [debug]> catch throw
   >   [debug]probe.c:59: internal-error: struct symtabs_and_lines parse_probes(char **, struct linespec_result *): Assertion `probe_ops != NULL' failed.
   >   [debug]A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
   >   [debug]further debugging may prove unreliable.
   >   Debugger finished with status 1
5. I have tried several versions of gdb (e.g., 7.6.2) with the same result.
6. One problem, it seems, is that I do not have the "Settings/Environment/General/Settings to launch terminal" set correctly.
7. I have successfully installed C::B (svn 9817) on an UBUNTU virtual machine (12.04) with gcc 4.2.1 & gdb 7.7.1.  The debugger seems to run OK on the UBUNTU VM.

Can you help me on my OSX version of C::B?

Skip